# Material-ui Next Theme Not applying

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to get a simple theme override set up on my project, but it doesn't seem to be applying.

Theme: (all it should do it change primary color to red, but it doesn't)

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        type: 'dark',
        primary: {
            light: red[300],
            main: red[500],
            dark: red[700],
        },
    },
    appBar: {
        height: 55,
    },
});
const styles = theme => ({})
```

Then I wrapped my whole app in MuiThemeProvider like so

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CssBaseline />,
            <Router>
                <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
                    <div>
                        <MaterialUiApp />
                    </div>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </Router>
        );
    }
} export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(App);
```

Yet it doesn't seem to be applying the theme to the elements in my app.  MaterialUiApp is just a wrapper for the various pieces of my main layout, such as two permanent drawers, appbar, and a content container (which currently has form elements in it).

Edit:  I can tell the default theme is properly applying by switching my AppBar color from primary to secondary, but it uses the default theme's colors instead of my own.

Edit:  [Here's the code on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7z52rrjmz1).

Comment: did you tried to export App directly, I mean `export default App`

Comment: Yes, it was originally that way.  I tried adding withStyles and withTheme to attempt to get it working.

Comment: I have a similar code and it works pretty well. Can you make a repro in codesandbox.io

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently my issue was with `muiTheme={theme}` in the MuiTheme element.  It should be just `theme={theme}` in material-ui beta.  I didn't realized they changed it.